# How do I stop Hibernate from deleting entities from DB which are not in list which I working with?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I working on a project where sometimes I need to get complex entity from DB with list of other entities inside:

```
@Entity
public class Operation{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // some fields

    private Status status;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "operation_id")
    private List<PathCord> path;

    private String name;

    // some fields

}
```

The entity from list:

```
@Entity
public class PathCord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private double x;
    private double y;
    boolean beenThere;
}
```

And sometimes I need to work with "Operation" entity with only few filtered PathCord's. Like this:

```
Operation operation = getLastOperationFromDB();

//some logic

operation.setPath(new ArrayList<>(operation.getPath().stream()
                .filter(pathCord -> !pathCord.isBeenThere())
                .toList()));

// do something

operation.setStatus(Status.COMPLETED);

operationRepository.save(operation);
```

The problem is that when repository updating the "Operation" it also deletes ALL the PathCord's which wasn't included in filtered list. But, I need just to update these PathCord's if they were changed or just leave the table unchanged if PathCord's remained untouched. Making different query for this operationt isn't an option. I need to get full list first.

I have already tried different variants of @OnDelete and @Cascade annotations, but I think I don't get how it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is removing the `PathCord` entities from the database because it treats the association between `Operation` and `PathCord` as the "owner" of the relationship. When you filter the list, Hibernate thinks that you've removed the entities from the `Operation` object, and it cascades the removal operation to these associated entities.

The simplest solution is to update the relationship annotation configuration in your `Operation` class:

1. You need to change the direction of the relationship owner. Make the `PathCord` entities the owner of the relationship instead of the `Operation`. This means changing the `@OneToMany` annotation in your `Operation` class to a `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "operation")`.
2. Use the `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false)` annotation on the `path` list inside your `Operation` entity. This will ensure that even if a `PathCord` is removed from an `Operation`'s `path` list, it will not be deleted from your database.
3. Add `@ManyToOne` annotation inside your `PathCord` class. This way you indicate `PathCord` is the owner of the relationship.

Here's how the code would look:

In your `Operation` class:

```java
@Entity
public class Operation{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // some fields

    private Status status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "operation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false)
    private List<PathCord> path;

    private String name;

    // some fields
}
```

In your `PathCord` class:

```java
@Entity
public class PathCord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private double x;
    private double y;
    boolean beenThere;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "operation_id")
    private Operation operation;
}
```

After making this change, if you want to remove a `PathCord` from an `Operation`, you'll have to do so explicitly using something like `pathCordRepository.delete(pathCord)`, or by setting its `Operation` value to `null`. Hibernate will no longer automatically remove `PathCords` that are removed from an `Operation`'s `path` list.